# Monte Carlo Simulation (estimating standard error using VAR function) matlab

Tags: matlab, variance

I've just started a course with matlab at school and struggling. just thought if anyone might give me a hand with this:

[image: question 1]

M is the number of trials, so it can be modded to 100, 1000 or 10000

[image: THis is the solution to the basic monte carlo simulation without variance involved]

Hope someone can give me a hand! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Looks like you've linked to your code in an image file. Would you be able to include it as a code block instead? (To put text within a code block, indent the text four spaces.)

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, but I don't quite understand what the problem is. So I will try and restate it, which might be what you really need.

You want to calculate the mean value of a specific variable, however, the real mean value is very difficult (read "impossible"), therefore one uses Monte-Carlo methods which generates a lot of samples, which one then can take the sample average of to obtain an approximation for the real mean value (due to the Central limit theorem). This is what the code generates.

You are now asked to find the error of this approximation. The error of a Monte-Carlo method is given as the variance of the estimator, which in this case means the square root of (bracket start) the variance of the samples (as generated above) divided by the number of samples (bracket end).

As well as the real mean value the real variance is unknown and is estimated as the sample variance, which is implemented into matlab with the function "var()".

Comment: Hi Nicky,

Thanks for your help on this. Yes that is exactly what i need.

The true variance is unknown hence substituted with sample variance of X trials. Which is done via VAR function. 

Thanks again:)